# Does Masstransit circuitbreaker logs anything when it opens/closes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I would like log in our application logs when circuitbreaker opens and closes. Is it something built in Masstransit? Any sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not built-in, there is no observer capability in the circuit breaker.